# Immigration stamps show through the back side of my passports pages. Is this a common problem?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, passport-stamps

I'm based in San Francisco and got a new Indian passport in Nov 2016. Since then, I've visited a couple of countries including in Schengen, New Zealand, Peru, Mexico, and Canada. I've noticed that there's always excess ink in the Schengen stamps across various airports (Frankfurt, Berlin, Brussels in my experience). As a result, unless I remove the excess ink with a tissue or boarding pass, it damages the other page.

I've seen the same with a few US stamps, but not Canada or New Zealand. The Peru stamp on my passport was also a bit "wet" and I didn't notice, but whatever.

This never happened with my previous Indian passport, which I used for Schengen, South Africa, US and a few others.

What's wrong here? Did Schengen decide to become more generous with their ink, or is this a problem with the paper quality of my  new passport?

[image: So wet!]

Comment: What you do is you put a tissue or napkin in the page where the stamp should go, then when the official flips to a random other page and stamps it, you snatch it out of his hand before he can slam it shut on the wet ink, and then you move the blotter to that page.  :-)  (And then you try to explain to the police that you did NOT assault a border official.)

Comment: I thought i was the only one to get impressions on boarding pass and count how high the number can go every time, aftee getting a exact mirror copy on opposite side.

Comment: Happened to my Schengen stamp as well.

Comment: Don't worry. Just point out that the characters are reversed. Remember, many countries like to use a CLEAN PAGE. If you have a PREVIOUS STAMP from a country, HAVE THEM USE THAT PAGE.

Comment: That's very odd. All of my Schengen stamps have been barely legible (and I have 8 of them, from three different countries). In fact, all of my passport stamps are barely legible, except the UK ones and my Jordanian entry stamp (though my Jordanian VOA is half missing).

Answer (score 1):

It's **common** and **not a problem**.  I've had that happen on my non-Indian passport, and nobody has ever complained -- and why would they?